# How to consolidate two sql server tables using Group By clause?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, group-by

I have two tables TableA and TableB as follows:

TableA:

```
     ItemID          Qty           Rate
    --------        -----         --------
       1             10            100.00
       2             20            150.00
```

TableB:

```
     ItemID          Qty           Rate
    --------        -----         -------
       1              5            150.00
       3              10           200.00
       3              20           400.00
```

Now I want to consolidate these two tables. My desired result needs to be as follows:

Result TableA:

```
     ItemID           Qty           Rate
    --------         -----         -------
       1              15            150.00
       2              20            150.00
       3              30            400.00
```

I tried the following Insert Select statement, But it does not give the desired result.

```
INSERT INTO TableA
(
     ItemID,
     Qty,
     Rate               
)
SELECT 
    ItemID, 
    SUM(Qty), 
    MAX(Rate)
FROM 
    TableB
GROUP BY 
    ItemID
```

But it gives the result as follows:

```
     ItemID          Qty           Rate
    --------        -----         --------
       1             10            100.00
       2             20            150.00
       1              5            150.00
       3              30           400.00
```

How to achieve my desired result?

I tried like this:

```
 MERGE PUR_PODetail AS Target
                USING (
                    SELECT 
                        @POID,
                        ItemID,
                        SUM(POQuantity),
                        MAX(UnitRate),
                        1,
                        CASE WHEN D1 = '' THEN NULL ELSE D1 END D1,
                        CASE WHEN D2 = '' THEN NULL ELSE D2 END D2,
                        CASE WHEN D3 = '' THEN NULL ELSE D3 END D3,
                        CASE WHEN RandomDimension = '' THEN NULL ELSE RandomDimension END RandomDimension,
                        0
                    FROM 
                        @Detail
                    GROUP BY 
                        ItemID, D1, D2, D3, RandomDimension
                    ) AS Source  ON (Target.ItemID = Source.ItemID) AND 
                    (ISNULL(Target.D1, -999) = ISNULL(Source.D1, -999)) AND 
                    (ISNULL(Target.D2, -999) = ISNULL(Source.D2, -999)) AND 
                    (ISNULL(Target.D3, -999) = ISNULL(Source.D3, -999)) AND
                    (ISNULL(Target.RandomDimension, -999) = ISNULL(Source.RandomDimension, -999))
                WHEN MATCHED
                    THEN UPDATE SET 
                            Target.POQuantity = Target.POQuantity + Source.POQuantity,
                            Target.UnitRate = MAX(Source.UnitRate)
                WHEN NOT MATCHED
                    INSERT
                        (
                            POID,
                            ItemID,
                            POQuantity,
                            UnitRate,
                            ItemStatusID,
                            D1,
                            D2,
                            D3,
                            RandomDimension,
                            EDInclusive_f
                        )
                    VALUES
                        (
                            @POID, 
                            Source.ItemID, 
                            Source.POQuantity, 
                            Source.UnitRate, 
                            1,
                            CASE WHEN Source.D1 = '' THEN NULL ELSE Source.D1 END D1,
                            CASE WHEN Source.D2 = '' THEN NULL ELSE Source.D2 END D2,
                            CASE WHEN Source.D3 = '' THEN NULL ELSE Source.D3 END D3,
                            CASE WHEN Source.RandomDimension = '' THEN NULL ELSE Source.RandomDimension END RandomDimension,
                            0
                        )
```

But it gives the following error.
Please correct the error. I dont know what would be wrong here.

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure PUR_PurchaseOrder_IU, Line 936
Incorrect syntax near 'MERGE'.
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure PUR_PurchaseOrder_IU, Line 953
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'.

But when I remove these merge statement from my stored procedure, it is executing...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just use the `INSERT` statement for this, you have to either `INSERT`or `UPDATE`depending on the ItemID already being present in your target table.

**SQL Server 2005**

```
UPDATE  @TableA
SET     Qty = a.Qty + b.Qty
        , Rate = CASE WHEN a.Rate < b.Rate
                      THEN b.Rate 
                      ELSE a.Rate 
                  END
FROM    @TableA a
        INNER JOIN (
          SELECT  ItemID
                  , Qty = SUM(Qty)
                  , Rate = MAX(Rate)
          FROM    @TableB
          GROUP BY 
                  ItemID  
        ) b ON a.ItemID = b.ItemID

INSERT INTO @TableA
SELECT  ItemID, Qty, Rate
FROM    ( SELECT  ItemID
                  , Qty = SUM(Qty)
                  , Rate = MAX(Rate)
          FROM    @TableB b
          WHERE   NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @TableA a WHERE a.ItemID = b.ItemID)
          GROUP BY 
                  ItemID  
        ) b
```

**SQL Server 2008 provides the [MERGE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510625.aspx) statement for this.**

> Performs insert, update, or delete operations on a target table based on the results of a join with a source table. For example, you
>   can synchronize two tables by inserting, updating, or deleting rows in
>   one table based on differences found in the other table.

**SQL Server 2008**

```
MERGE @TableA AS Target
USING (
  SELECT  ItemID
          , Qty = SUM(Qty)
          , Rate = MAX(Rate)
  FROM    @TableB
  GROUP BY 
          ItemID  
) AS source (ItemID, Qty, Rate) ON (target.ItemID = source.ItemID)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
  UPDATE SET target.Qty = target.Qty + source.Qty
             , target.Rate = CASE WHEN target.Rate < source.Rate 
                                  THEN source.Rate 
                                  ELSE target.Rate 
                             END
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN
  INSERT (ItemID, Qty, Rate)
  VALUES (source.ItemID, source.Qty, source.Rate);
```

Comment: Note, that rates are not summarizing - but taking the max value. Please, correct the answer

Comment: @Lieven: Hi, I edited my question. Please have a look at it. I tried like what you had given but it gives the error. Please tell me what is wrong in it.

Comment: @thevan - Besides a missing `;`at the end of the statement, I don't see anything wrong with it.

Comment: @Lieven: I am using SQL SERVER 2005. So it is not executing in my stored procedure.

Comment: @thevan - I would suggest to try to run the merge statement in and by itself and report the error back here. If you don't get an error, at least we'll know it is not a simple syntax error we both overlooked.

Comment: @Lieven: I tried what you had said. But I am using SQL SERVER 2005. I get the following error "Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure PUR_PurchaseOrder_IU, Line 936 Incorrect syntax near 'MERGE'. Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure PUR_PurchaseOrder_IU, Line 953 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'AS'." What would be the reason?

Comment: @thevan - duh, I completely missed the fact that MERGE is not available in SQL Server 2005. I have altered the answer for an SQL Server 2005 solution.

Comment: @thevan - Don't mention it, sorry about the hickup wasting time.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
MERGE TableA T
USING
(
  SELECT ItemId, SUM(Qty) Qty, MAX(Rate) Rate
  FROM
  (
   SELECT ItemId, Qty, Rate from TableA
   UNION ALL
   SELECT ItemId, Qty, Rate from TableB
) S
ON T.ItemId = S.ItemId
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET
  Qty = S.Qty,
  Rate= S.Rate
WHEN NOT MATCHED THEN 
  INSERT(ItemId, Qty, Rate)
  VALUES(S.ItemId, S.Qty, S.Rate);
```

Comment: Hi, I edited my question. Please have a look at it and what is wrong in my merge statement.

Answer (score 0):

declare @t table (ItemID int,Qty int,Rate int)
insert into @t values (1,10,100),(2,20,150)

Select * from @t

declare @t1 table (ItemID int,Qty int,Rate int)
insert into @t1 values (1,5,150),(3,10,200),(3,20,400)

Select * from @t1

insert into @t
Select ItemID,sum(Qty) Qty,max(Rate) Rate from @t1 where ItemID not in (Select ItemID from @t) 
group by ItemID

Select * from @t